# Buggy home-made code to benchmark memory and time in Bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, memory-management, resources, ps

**The Bash code**

I wrote this small code to measure time and peak in memory usage of a process.

```
# Get arguments
MaxMemory="$1"
MaxTime="$2"
Command="$3"
for (( i=4 ; i<="$#"; i++)); do
    Command="${Command} ${!i}"
done

echo -e "MaxMemory = ${MaxMemory}\nMaxTime = ${MaxTime}\nCommand = ${Command}"


#### run the given Command in the background
${Command} &


#### Get pid
pid=$!
echo "pid = ${pid}"


#### Monitor resources
MemoryPeak=0
timeBefore=$(date +"%s")
while true;do
        # Get memory
        mem=$(ps -o rss,pid | grep ${pid} | awk '{print $1}')

        # Break if the process has stopped running
        if [[ ${mem} == "" ]]; then
                #echo "process has stopped"
                break
        fi

        # Set the MemoryPeak of memory
        if [ "${mem}" -gt "${MemoryPeak}" ]; then
                MemoryPeak=$mem
        fi

        # If it consumed too much memory, then kill
        if [ "${MemoryPeak}" -gt "${MaxMemory}" ];then
                #echo "process consumed too much memory"
                kill ${pid}
                break
        fi

        # If it consumed too much CPU time, then kill
        timeAfter=$(date +"%s")
        timeUsage=$((timeAfter - timeBefore))
        if [ "${timeUsage}" -gt "${MaxTime}" ];then
                #echo "process consumed too much time"
                kill ${pid}
                break
        fi

        # sleep
        sleep 0.1
done

timeAfter=$(date +"%s")
timeUsage=$((timeAfter - timeBefore))

echo "MEM ${MemoryPeak} TIME ${timeUsage}"
```

The command called `memAndTime` works as in

```
memAndTime ${MaxMemory} ${MaxTime} ./myProcess arg1 arg2 arg3
```

**Question**

I am not here to discuss reasons why I am not using `timeout`, `gtimeout`, `memusg` or `ulimit`.

The code sometimes send the following series of error messages

```
264: integer expression expected
/usr/bin/memAndTime: line 36: [: 473268
644
912
372: integer expression expected
/usr/bin/memAndTime: line 36: [: 705108
652: integer expression expected
/usr/bin/memAndTime: line 36: [: 842760
384: integer expression expected
```

The line 36 is

```
if [ "${mem}" -gt "${MemoryPeak}" ]; then
```

it feels like the object `mem` built in `mem=$(ps -o rss,pid | grep ${pid} | awk '{print $1}')` can sometimes start with a column.

I fail to reproduce the error message outside the usage of this command. Also, the error message is rare enough to make it difficult to reproduce. I fail to understand what is causing it. Can you help finding out the source of this error message and how to fix it?

Comment: Find a reliable solution for: `mem=$(ps -o rss,pid | grep ${pid} | awk '{print $1}')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command in your shell:

```
[ s -gt 1 ]
```

The output should be something like this:

> ```
> -bash: [: s: integer expression expected
> ```

That is: *one line of error message*.

What do we see in your output?

> ```
> /usr/bin/memAndTime: line 36: [: 705108
> 652: integer expression expected
> ```

That's 2 lines! How could that be?

How many lines do you have in `mem` after this command?

> ```
> mem=$(ps -o rss,pid | grep ${pid} | awk '{print $1}')
> ```

You probably assume it's one, but it can be more. Here's a superficial way to make sure it always contains at most one value:

```
mem=$(ps -o rss,pid | grep ${pid} | awk '{print $1; exit}')
```

And here's a better, robust way:

```
mem=$(ps -o rss= -p $pid)
```

The `=` in the `-o` parameter can be used to specify a custom header. Just appending `=` means empty header. If the headers of all columns are empty, the header is omitted from the output, so need for additional processes like `tail` or others to remove it.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!